# How to prove Convex Analysis(Rockafellar) Corollary 32.4.1?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Corollary 32.4.1. Let $f$ be a proper convex function, and let $S$ be a non-empty set on which $f$ is not constant. Suppose the supremum of $f$ relative to $S$ is attained at a certain point $x \in \operatorname{ri}(\operatorname{dom} f)$. Then every $x^* \in \partial f(x)$ is a non-zero vector such that the linear function $\left\langle\cdot, x^*\right\rangle$ attains its supremum relative to $S$ at $x$.

> Proof. Let $C=$ conv $S$. By Theorem 32.2, the supremum of $f$ relative to $C$ is the same as the supremum relative to $S$. The supremum is $f(x)$, which is finite because $x \in \operatorname{ri}(\operatorname{dom} f)$. The theorem can be applied to $C$. Thus every $x^* \in \partial f(x)$ is a non-zero vector normal to $C$ at $x$. The normality means that the linear function $\left\langle\cdot, x^*\right\rangle$ attains its supremum relative to $C$ (which is again the supremum relative to $S$ ) at $x$.

I can not understand how to prove "The normality means that the linear function $\left\langle\cdot, x^*\right\rangle$ attains its supremum relative to $C$ (which is again the supremum relative to $S$ ) at $x$."  Why "normality" equivalent “sup<x*,C>=<x,x*>”?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $x^*$ is a *normal* vector to $C$ at $x$, i.e.,
$$
\langle x^*, y-x \rangle \le 0 \quad \forall y\in C.
$$
Since $S\subset C$, the claim follows.

Comment: Sorry, i understand that $\left\langle x^*, y-x\right\rangle \leqslant 0 \quad \forall y \in C$, but then i only obtain $sup<x*,C>\leqslant <x,x*>$. Then, we should show $sup<x*,C>\geqslant <x,x*>$.How to show the backwards？

Comment: because $x\in C$.

Comment: Very thanks, and i can guess that $x\in C$, but the condition in this  Corollary is $x\in ri(domf)$. How to explain: $x\in C$? Or am I missing any details? Thank you.

Comment: From the assumptions, $x\in S$, which is ofc $\subset conv(S)=C$.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Thank you very much！